# Rotating an NSImage in Swift

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

I'm trying to rotate an image 90 degrees on Mac OS using Swift. 
I've the following code:

```
@IBAction func rotateImage(_ sender: Any) {
    let rotatedImage = image.imageRotatedByDegrees(degrees: CGFloat(90))
    self.imageView?.image = rotatedImage
}
```

And

```
public extension NSImage {
    public func imageRotatedByDegrees(degrees:CGFloat) -> NSImage {

        var imageBounds = NSZeroRect
        imageBounds.size = self.size
        let pathBounds = NSBezierPath(rect: imageBounds)
        var transform = NSAffineTransform()
        transform.rotate(byDegrees: degrees)
        pathBounds.transform(using: transform as AffineTransform)
        let rotatedBounds:NSRect = NSMakeRect(NSZeroPoint.x, NSZeroPoint.y , self.size.width, self.size.height )
        let rotatedImage = NSImage(size: rotatedBounds.size)

        //Center the image within the rotated bounds
        imageBounds.origin.x = NSMidX(rotatedBounds) - (NSWidth(imageBounds) / 2)
        imageBounds.origin.y  = NSMidY(rotatedBounds) - (NSHeight(imageBounds) / 2)

        // Start a new transform
        transform = NSAffineTransform()
        // Move coordinate system to the center (since we want to rotate around the center)
        transform.translateX(by: +(NSWidth(rotatedBounds) / 2 ), yBy: +(NSHeight(rotatedBounds) / 2))
        transform.rotate(byDegrees: degrees)
        // Move the coordinate system bak to normal
        transform.translateX(by: -(NSWidth(rotatedBounds) / 2 ), yBy: -(NSHeight(rotatedBounds) / 2))
        // Draw the original image, rotated, into the new image
        rotatedImage.lockFocus()
        transform.concat()
        self.draw(in: imageBounds, from: NSZeroRect, operation: NSCompositingOperation.copy, fraction: 1.0)
        rotatedImage.unlockFocus()

        return rotatedImage
    }
}
```

Initially the image looks like this:

[image]

Once I rotate the image it gets cropped to a square. So it looks like this:

[image]

This is undesired behaviour. I want it to have the same dimensions as before.

Comment: It's not that it's square, it that's you've rotated the image 90°, but inside the original (portrait) rectangle. I suspect what you want to do is flip the `height` & `width` of `rotatedBounds` so the new image is as wide as the original image was high, and vice versa.

Comment: Footnote: you're actually generating a new `NSImage` from the original. If all you want to do is *display* a rotated image, consider setting the view's `frameRotation` (and you'll probably have to move its `bounds` origin to keep it centered).